# Is there a Lua string replace() function for faster replacements than gsub()?

Tags: string, replace, lua

I see a list of Lua string functions and I see the `.gsub()`, for global search and replace: http://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?general=lua_string

All lua string functions :

```
static const luaL_Reg strlib[] = {
  {"byte", str_byte},
  {"char", str_char},
  {"dump", str_dump},
  {"find", str_find},
  {"format", str_format},
  {"gfind", gfind_nodef},
  {"gmatch", gmatch},
  {"gsub", str_gsub},
  {"len", str_len},
  {"lower", str_lower},
  {"match", str_match},
  {"rep", str_rep},
  {"reverse", str_reverse},
  {"sub", str_sub},
  {"upper", str_upper},
  {NULL, NULL}
};
```

Why is there no simple, fast, litteral (non-regex) string replace function?
Is `.gsub()` so efficient that there is no benefit?

I found this written in 2006 but it does not seem like it's included: http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringReplace

Comment: Using a table in gsub is probably faster than using a function.

Comment: Can you add more please? I'm having some difficulty understanding the advice, but would gladly try it once I understand it.

Comment: "*Why is there no simple, fast, litteral (non-regex) replace function?*" That replaces what with what?

Comment: Please give examples of what replacements you have in mind.

Comment: String with string. Corrected in the question.

Comment: Are you running into performance issues with [`gsub`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lstrlib.c.html#str_gsub)? What other use is there for a plain text search and replace, when `gsub` can already do this with relative efficiency. Even Penlight's interpretation of [`replace`](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/master/lua/pl/stringx.lua#L234) is just a couple of calls to `gsub`. Regardless, you could fairly easily package that snippet you've found into a module.

Comment: I'm not asking for practical advice, just for a reason why there is no such method, which seems sensible to include. A theoretical consultation. Maybe it was decided for some reason in the LUA community, not to have them. Maybe gsub performance is close enough to the best possible performance of any literal replace function. Let me know :)

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius Likely because `gsub` is capable of doing exactly what this `replace` function would do, and Lua's designs goals include that of a small, generally uncomplicated standard library. There's no need for a redundancy like this. Again, Lua is an extensible language - it's very, very easy to add this functionality in if _you_ need it. Most people don't need it, though.

Comment: Thanks, I have just read for 10-15 minutes about the design goals of lua. Can you include this as an answer to the question? I presume if small library is one of the design goals, generality of methods will be favored over specificity, wonder how that impacts performance ... Please formulate the above toughs as the answers, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely because [`gsub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) is capable of doing exactly what a `replace` function would do, and Lua's [design goals](http://www.lua.org/about.html) include that of a small, generally uncomplicated standard library. There's no need for a redundancy like this to be baked right into the language.

As an outside example, the Ruby programming language provides both `String#gsub` and `String#replace` in its standard library. Ruby is a much, much larger language out of the box because of decisions like this.

However, Lua prides itself on being a very easy language to extend. The link you've shown shows how to bake the function into the standard library when compiling Lua as a whole. You could also piece it together to create a module.

Quickly patching together the parts we need results in (note we need the `lmemfind` function from [lstrlib.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lstrlib.c.html#lmemfind)):

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char *lmemfind
(const char *s1, size_t l1, const char *s2, size_t l2) {
    if (l2 == 0)
        return s1;  /* empty strings are everywhere */
    else if (l2 > l1)
        return NULL;  /* avoids a negative 'l1' */

    const char *init;  /* to search for a '*s2' inside 's1' */
    l2--;  /* 1st char will be checked by 'memchr' */
    l1 = l1-l2;  /* 's2' cannot be found after that */

    while (l1 > 0 && (init = (const char *) memchr(s1, *s2, l1)) != NULL) {
        init++;   /* 1st char is already checked */

        if (memcmp(init, s2+1, l2) == 0)
            return init-1;
        else {  /* correct 'l1' and 's1' to try again */
            l1 -= init-s1;
            s1 = init;
        }
    }

    return NULL;  /* not found */
}

static int str_replace(lua_State *L) {
    size_t l1, l2, l3;
    const char *src = luaL_checklstring(L, 1, &l1);
    const char *p = luaL_checklstring(L, 2, &l2);
    const char *p2 = luaL_checklstring(L, 3, &l3);
    const char *s2;
    int n = 0;
    int init = 0;

    luaL_Buffer b;
    luaL_buffinit(L, &b);

    while (1) {
        s2 = lmemfind(src+init, l1-init, p, l2);
        if (s2) {
            luaL_addlstring(&b, src+init, s2-(src+init));
            luaL_addlstring(&b, p2, l3);
            init = init + (s2-(src+init)) + l2;
            n++;
        } else {
            luaL_addlstring(&b, src+init, l1-init);
            break;
        }
    }

    luaL_pushresult(&b);
    lua_pushnumber(L, (lua_Number) n);  /* number of substitutions */
    return 2;
}

int luaopen_strrep (lua_State *L) {
    lua_pushcfunction(L, str_replace);
    return 1;
}
```

We can compile this into a shared object with the proper linkage (`cc -shared`, `cc -bundle`, etc...), and load it into Lua like any other module with `require`.

```
local replace = require 'strrep'

print(replace('hello world', 'hello', 'yellow')) -- yellow world, 1.0
```

*This answer is a formalized reconstruction of the comments above.*